# SugarCRM Python API Wrapper - "NoneType" object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, sugarcrm

I downloaded the SugarCRM Python API wrapper from [Github](https://github.com/sugarcrm/python_webservices_library/downloads)

Trying out the basic login code, I have the following problem

```
 >>> url = 'http://<REDACTED>/service/v2/rest.php'
 >>> user = '<REDACTED>'
 >>> passwd = '<REDACTED>'
 >>> import sugarcrm
 >>> session = sugarcrm.Sugarcrm(url, user, passwd)
 Connecting to: http://<REDACTED>/service/v2/rest.php
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sugarcrm/sugarcrm.py", line 58, in __init__
self.login(username, password)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sugarcrm/sugarcrm.py", line 112, in login
self.id = x["id"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround here:
https://github.com/sugarcrm/python_webservices_library/issues/3